# How can I make an element center horizontally?

Tags: html, css, centering

I have the following HTML structure:

```css
.parent{
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 60%;
}

.child2{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <a href="#" class="child1">it should stay in the left side</a>
  <br>
  <a href="#" class="child2">this should be center</a>
</div>
```

I need to center `a.child2` . I can do this by adding `text-align: center` to `div.parent`. But in that case, `a.child1` will be centered too and I don't want to.

As you can see, I've also added `margin: 0 auto;` to `a.child2`, but  it is still placed on the left side.

To sum up, how can I center `a.child2`  while mantaining `a.child1` on the left side?

Answer (score 3):

Set `display` property as `block` show them in different line. And then apply text-align property to the `.child2` to align text in center.

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 60%;
}
.parent a {
  display: block;
}
.child2 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <a href="#" class="child1">it should stay in the left side</a>
  <a href="#" class="child2">this should be center</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

set `.child2` to `display:table`

```css
.parent{
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 60%;
}

.child2{
  margin:auto;
  display:table
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <a href="#" class="child1">it should stay in the left side</a>
  <br>
  <a href="#" class="child2">this should be center</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can center using `display: table` and `margin: 0 auto` which is already in place.

```css
.parent{
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 60%;
}

.child2{
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <a href="#" class="child1">it should stay in the left side</a>
  <br>
  <a href="#" class="child2">this should be center</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind, you can make child2 display inline-block and width 100%, then you can center its content.

```css
.parent{
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 60%;

}

.child2{
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <a href="#" class="child1">it should stay in the left side</a>
  <br>
  <a href="#" class="child2">this should be center</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the `margin: 0 auto` to work there are few things you need to keep in mind.

- The element must `display: block`
- The element must **not** float
- The element must **not** have a fixed or absolute position
- The element must have a `width` that is not auto.

So in your case only 2 things were missing - `width` & `display: block`(since `<a>` is by default `display:inline-block`). This should fix

```
.child2{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:40%;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put those lines in `p` tags and assign `text-align: center` to the second one:

```css
.parent{
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 60%;
}

.child2{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<p class="child1">
  <a href="#" >it should stay in the left side</a>
  </p>
<p class="child2">
  <a href="#">this should be center</a>
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: If you have access to the html, this approach would be my preferred one. But I would replace the `p` by `li` and make `div.parent` a `ul`.

Comment: if it's a navigation menu, yes

Comment: I don't see what this would have to do with it being a navigation element or not. Unordered lists are the right elements to use when you have a list of items that have a common semantic origin.

Comment: exactly - which a nagivation menu is good example for...